# htaccess rewrite - 404 on existing file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

So I have the following rewrite in an htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Whenever I try to go to `http://domain/index` I get a 404, but when I try to go to `http://domain/index.` or even a non-existent page like `http://domain/a`, the rewrite works just fine and index.php `var_dump()`s the appropriate values.

The only code in index.php is `var_dump($_GET);`, so I know it's not a php issue.

Can someone explain to me what's wrong with my rewrite rule, and explain how to fix it?

**EDIT:**
I forgot I had error logging enabled. The error it keeps saving to error.log is:

```
[Sun Feb 24 21:01:18 2013] [error] [client 192.168.1.1] Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: /path/public_html/index (None could be negotiated).
```

Comment: You may try this: `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/? index.php?page=$1 [L]` and it would be a good idea to add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php [NC]` before that rule to prevent loops.

Comment: Now the page dumps "index.php" as the value of `$_GET['page']` regardless of anything. /index also still gives a 404.

Comment: Use [R,L] so you can see the substitution URL and `var_dump($_SERVER)` in the script to see all server variables.

Comment: By the error, seems you have `MultiViews` enabled. Try adding this: `Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews` at the top.

Comment: Using [R,L] revealed nothing. The other pages redirect properly still, and /index loads the same URL with a 404 result.

Comment: The `-Multiviews` did it. If you make that an answer and either explain briefly what it does or provide a link, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the error, it seems MultiViews is enabled.

You may try this at the top of the file:

`Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews`

Additionally, I suggest the following:

```
# Prevent loops
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/? index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

MultiViews provides for  `Content Negotiation`, best described [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_negotiation.html)

Answer (score 1):

When `MultiViews` is enabled (`Options +MultiViews`), the [`Content Negotiation`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_negotiation.html) module looks for files that match `index`, but `.php` files don't qualify for a match, so it fails with `None could be negotiated`.  You can add `.php` handlers as matches using:

```
MultiviewsMatch Handlers Filters
```

as documented in [`MultiviewsMatch`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#multiviewsmatch).